# Symfony 3.4 Global Variable

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, postgis

I am developing a platform of webmapping, It's about geolocalized data of the Mediterranean Sea (e.g Salinity, pH, pCO2 etc...) took from a boat that travels between Tunis, Marseille and Genova.

The names of the parameters (salinity, pH...) retrieved from the sea can change according to dictionaries, but the values still the same (ofc).

So what I want to do is after I save the parameters names and dictionaries, I want to choose a dictionary to work with as globally in the app, all the data shown in the app must be under parameters names retrieved from the chosen dictionary.

I want to add a ChoiceType form in the header in which I will select the desired dictionary and work with in the whole app. The chosen dictionary will be saved as enabled in the data base.

The question is, what is the best way to do this?

Here is shown my entities:

Dictionaries

```
/**


* ParamDictionary
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="param_dictionary")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\ParamDictionaryRepository")
 */

class ParamDictionary
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;
```

Parameters Names

```
 /**
 * ParamName
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="param_name")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\ParamNameRepository")
 */

class ParamName
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var ParamReference
     *
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\ParamReference")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $reference;

    /**
     * @var ParamDictionary
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\ParamDictionary")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dictionary_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $dictionary;
```

Parameters references

```
/**
 * ParamReference
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="param_reference")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\ParamReferenceRepository")
 */

class ParamReference
{


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;
```

Parameters Values

```
/**
* ParamValue
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="param_value")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\ParamValueRepository")
 */
class ParamValue

{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="decimal", precision=16, scale=8)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @var Meas
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Meas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meas_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $meas;

    /**
     * @var ParamName
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\ParamReference")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $reference;
```

Geolocalized Data point

```
/**
 * Meas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="meas")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\MeasRepository")
 */

class Meas
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date_time;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="decimal", precision=16, scale=8)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="decimal", precision=16, scale=8)
     */
    private $longitude;
```